# Subclass doesn't display Processing

Tags: tree, processing, superclass, display, flower

I'm working on an assignment that needs to create a base class Tree, with subclass Flower. 
But I don't know where I get it wrong, the flowers don't appear on the tree when mouse is pressed, only the tree appears. Here is my code so far,

```java
Tree tree;
ArrayList<Tree> treeList = new ArrayList<Tree>();

Flower flowers;
ArrayList <Flower> flowerList = new ArrayList<Flower>();

void setup() {
  size(800, 800);
  tree = new Tree(mouseX, mouseY, HALF_PI, height/12);
  flowers = new Flower(mouseX, mouseY, HALF_PI, height/12);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);

  //current tree
  for (int j =0; j < treeList.size(); j++)
  {
    tree = treeList.get(j);
    tree.drawTree(tree.xPos, tree.yPos, tree.rotation, tree.tall);
  }

  //current flower
  for(int i = 0; i < flowerList.size(); i ++){
    flowers = flowerList.get(i);
    flowers.drawFlower();
  }
drawMouseTree(mouseX, mouseY, HALF_PI, height/12);

}

void mousePressed() {
  treeList.add(new Tree(mouseX, mouseY, HALF_PI, height/12));
  flowerList.add(new Flower(mouseX, mouseY, HALF_PI, height/12));
}

void drawMouseTree(float xPos, float yPos, float rotation, float tall) {
  //growing branch 
  float endX = xPos - tall * cos(rotation);
  float endY = yPos - tall * sin(rotation);

  //draw a tree
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(2);
  line(xPos, yPos, endX, endY);

  //create 2 branches 
  if (tall > 5 ) {
    drawMouseTree(endX, endY, rotation - PI/5, tall * 0.7); //left
    drawMouseTree(endX, endY, rotation + PI/5, tall * 0.7); //right
  }

  //create flowers each branch
  if (tall > 5 ) {

    stroke(255,102,178);
    fill(255, 102, 178);
    ellipse(endX, endY, 5, 5);
  }
}


class Tree {
  float xPos, yPos;
  float rotation;
  float tall, endX, endY;

  Tree(float xPos, float yPos, float rotation, float tall) {
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.rotation = rotation;
    this.tall = tall;
  }

  void drawTree(float xPos, float yPos, float rotation, float tall) {
    //end of a branch
    float endX = xPos - tall * cos(rotation);
    float endY = yPos - tall * sin(rotation);

    //draw a tree
    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(2);
    line(xPos, yPos, endX, endY);

    //create 2 branches 
    if (tall > 5) {
      drawTree(endX, endY, rotation - PI/5, tall * 0.7); //left
      drawTree(endX, endY, rotation + PI/5, tall * 0.7); //right
    }
  }
}

class Flower extends Tree {

  Flower(float xPos, float yPos, float rotation, float tall) {
    super(xPos, yPos, rotation, tall);
  }


  void drawFlower() {
    super.drawTree(xPos, yPos, rotation, tall);

    //create flowers each branch
    if (tall < 40 && tall > 5) { //so the flowers will appear around top of tree


      stroke(255, 102, 178);
      fill(255, 102, 178);
      ellipse(endX, endY, 5, 5);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm still new to the super-child class concept. Any help to fix this would be very appreciated!

**Edit:**
Find out my mistake of using endX, endY in drawFlower(). Here is the new code:

```java
class Flower extends Tree {

  Flower(float xPos, float yPos, float rotation, float tall) {
    super(xPos, yPos, rotation, tall);
  }

  void drawFlower() {
    super.drawTree(xPos, yPos, rotation, tall);
    //create flowers each branch

    if (tall > 5 ) {
      //draw flower

      stroke(255, 102, 178);
      fill(255, 102, 178);
      ellipse(finX, finY, 5, 5);

    }
  }
}
class Tree {
  float xPos, yPos;
  float rotation;
  float tall, finX, finY;

  Tree(float xPos, float yPos, float rotation, float tall) {
    this.xPos = xPos;
    this.yPos = yPos;
    this.rotation = rotation;
    this.tall = tall;
  }

  void drawTree(float xPos, float yPos, float rotation, float tall) {
    //end of a branch
    float endX = xPos - tall * cos(rotation);
    float endY = yPos - tall * sin(rotation);
    finX = endX;
    finY = endY;

    //draw a tree
    stroke(0);
    strokeWeight(2);
    line(xPos, yPos, endX, endY); //branch

    //create 2 branches 
    if (tall > 5) {

      drawTree(endX, endY, rotation - PI/5, tall * 0.7); //left
      drawTree(endX, endY, rotation + PI/5, tall * 0.7); //right
    }
  }
}
```

However, the result is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTzOK.png 
Is there anyway to have a flower on **each end branch** of the tree? 
Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTdiV.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `height` of your window is `800`.

The last parameter you pass into the `Tree` or `Flower` constructor is `height/12`.

`800/12` is `66.6666...`, which gets truncated to `66`.

In other words, the `tall` variable holds the value `66`. You then use that variable in this `if` statement:

```java
if (tall < 40 && tall > 5) {
```

This `if` statment never evaluates to true, since `66` is **not** less than `40`.

You can easily test this yourself by simply printing out the value of `tall` right before that `if` statement:

```java
println(tall);
```

Even if you comment that `if` statement out, you still won't see flowers. Again, the `println()` function to the rescue:

```java
  stroke(255, 102, 178);
  fill(255, 102, 178);
  println(endX + ", " + endY); //prints 0.0, 0.0
  ellipse(endX, endY, 50, 50);
```

The value of `endX` and `endY` is always `0` at this point. And that makes sense with how you're using them.

I see what you're going for here, but at this point in the code you don't really have access to the end position of the branches.

If I were you, I'd start out much simpler. Instead of using a recursive function to draw your trees, start out with a single line with a flower at the top, then go from there.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I should have mentioned that it must be a recursive tree, with some subclasses as requirement.

Comment: @Tracey Even if that's your requirement, I still recommend starting simpler. Your problems stem from not really understanding the code yet, so the best thing you can do is start simpler. Try creating a more basic sketch that just shows a flower at the end of a straight tree, and then work your way up from there.